# Loading Temporary DLLs into Python on Win32

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

A common idiom I have seen in various Python code bases to dynamically generate/load a C function at runtime is:

```
import tempfile
import shutil
from ctypes import CDLL

workdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    # Generate and write code in workdir
    # ...
    # Compile and link into an .so/.dylib/.dll
    # ...
    lib = CDLL(path_to_lib)
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(workdir)
```

While this appears to work quite nicely on *nix systems I am unsure how well it will work on Win32.  This is because, in my experience, when the .dll inside the temporary directory is mapped into the process it is not possible to unlink it.  Hence, `rmtree` will fail.

What options are available to me to ensure that on Win32 the .dll (and the directory in which it resides) are deleted ASAP (so as soon as the underlying `lib` has been gc'ed or when the application terminates so as not to leave temporary cruft about).

Answer (score 2):

Use the Kernel32 function [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683152) to unmap the DLL and decrement its reference count. To get the handle you can use [`GetModuleHandleW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199), but it's already available in the `_handle` attribute.

**Edit:** The underlying `_ctypes` module already provides this function as well as `dlclose` for POSIX. If there's an error these functions raise `WindowsError` / `OSError`.

```
>>> import os                               
>>> from ctypes import *  
>>> from _ctypes import FreeLibrary

>>> lib = CDLL('./lib.dll')
>>> hlib = lib._handle
>>> del lib
>>> FreeLibrary(hlib)

>>> os.remove('./lib.dll')
>>> os.path.exists('./lib.dll')
False
```

Comment: In general one wishes to use `lib` for an undetermined period of time.  Hence, I am wondering if it is possible to say mark the dir and directory for deletion (so Windows will handle the cleanup).

Comment: @FreddieWitherden: I haven't looked into that. You could register a Python [atexit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit) function to free the library and remove the directory.

Comment: @FreddieWitherden Your comment is at odds with the question. This answer (+1) addresses the question that you asked. If you want the system to delete a DLL when it's no longer in use, I don't think that's possible.